# IIS sites stop responding unless Remote Desktop session is active

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have had this issue for quite a while, but I have never figured out what is causing it. The hosting company has not been much help since my server is un-managed.

The problem is, unless I have an active remote desktop session to my server, my web sites I have hosted via IIS do not respond. Once I connect via RDP the sites are responsive again. I have never run into this issue with other services. Its almost like the system is sleeping, but the power options are not set to sleep.

I am running windows Server 2012 R2.

**UPDATE**

This is still an issue. I am thinking it may be an actual server issue rather than windows.

**Update 06/04**

This is still happening even after updating the ports. No idea why this is happening still.

Comment: Which user credentials are used for your IIS services? Should be `local system` or some such. Can you ping the server when _not_ connected via RDP?

Comment: Both WAS and WWW Publishing are running under the local system account. Yes, I can ping the server. It's really bizarre.

Comment: Anything in the event / IIS logs? Startup of services etc., maybe enable debug logging?

Comment: Nothing stands out in the event logs either. Debug logging would have to be put on each site. I would see events in the Application Log if there were uncaught exceptions. It's really frustrating.

Comment: @Lenniey, could this be a DNS issue?

Comment: Did you try to access the sites from different clients? E.g. not the one you're RDPing with? And: can't find a reason as to why this could be a DNS issue. What's the response code from your browser if you try to connect?

Comment: Yes, I have tried other clients and have the same result. There is no response code, the connection times out. Its as if the server, itself, is not accessible via HTTP. I can RDP, ping, etc. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Sounds like a strange firewall (or routing) problem to me. Enable firewall logs and check them (or temporarily disable it completely). Do you access your IIS directly or through some firewall or reverse proxy?

Comment: I have a dedicated sever and access to IIS and the windows firewall. I do not have access to the hosting company's firewall, however.

Comment: So, did you try to temporarily disable the firewall?

Comment: I did disable the windows firewall, this morning. It seems that may be the issue. There is nothing funky in the rules either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55019/discussion-between-ddivita-and-lenniey).

Comment: @Lenniey, There was a rule denying port 1900. It seems after removing that rule, the server has not had any issues. Is port 1900 used for anything that could stop communication to the server? It seems odd that communication would be regained by RDPing back into the server.

Comment: Maybe the rule was internally connected to some different ports / programs / whatever. Port 1900 is a non-standard port (but used by UPnP), so it should not affect RDP or anything directly, but "you never know" what any configuration, which you didn't create yourself, affects. If your problems are solved, answer your question so the topic is closed. Glad it works now :)

Answer (score 2):

I have just had the same issue with an IIS Server, exactly as you describe. We are using AD to authenticate users, turns out that the IIS Server couldn't see the Domain Controller server, as soon as you start an RDP session it all starts working. So I added the Domain Controller IP address into the Hosts file on the IIS server and it is all working now. Not sure in your case what you are using for authentication but it might be a routing issue as well.